# Auto Layout: view height is always zero

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have code something like this in viewDidLoad:

```
UIView *parentView = [[UIView alloc] init];
parentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

UIView *topView = nil;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    nameLabel.text = self.data[i];
    nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [parentView addSubview:nameLabel];

    UIImageView *clockIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    clockIconView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img"];
    clockIconView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [parentView addSubview:clockIconView];

    UILabel *timeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    timeLabel.text = self.time;
    timeLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [parentView addSubview:timeLabel];

    [parentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[nameLabel(>=150)]-[clockIconView(20)]-1-[timeLabel(39)]-|"
                                                                           options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline
                                                                           metrics:nil
                                                                             views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(nameLabel, clockIconView, timeLabel)]];

    // First view - add constraint to superview
    if (i == 0) {
        [parentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[nameLabel(20)]"
                                                                               options:0
                                                                               metrics:nil
                                                                                 views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(nameLabel)]];
    }

    // Add constraint to previous view
    if (topView) {
        [parentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[topView]-[nameLabel(20)]"
                                                                               options:0
                                                                               metrics:nil
                                                                                 views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(nameLabel, topView)]];
    }

    // Last view - add constraint to superview's bottom
    if (i == 2) {
        [parentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[nameLabel(20)]-|"
                                                                               options:0
                                                                               metrics:nil
                                                                                 views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(nameLabel)]];
    }

    [parentView layoutIfNeeded];
    topView = nameLabel;
}

NSLog(@"%@", parentView);
```

First, I add horizontal constraints to align labels and an imageView. Then, I create vertical constraints.

However, `parentView`'s frame has negative origin x and height is always 0. Can't figure out why. Any ideas why height is zero?

```
<UIView: 0x17037b600; frame = (-129 0; 258 0); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x170036da0>>
```

Comment: `1.` `UIView` designated initialiser is `initWithFrame:` NOT `init` so `parentView` is not correctly initialised. `2.` You are not adding `parentView` to any superview nor setting any constraints on it (e.g. to make it the size of the screen) so it's not clear that it ever has a "correct" size `3.` Neither `clockIconView` nor `timeLabel` appear to have any height set - do they have intrinsic size? `4.` I worry about fixing the `i == 2` `nameLabel` to the bottom of the view as well as fixing it to the `topView`. Have you tested this in the Storyboard and seen what errors are created?

Comment: In your vertical constraint, can you try pinning the bottom of the subviews to the bottom of the superview?

Comment: @RoboticCat `1.` I thought `init` initializes a `UIView` with (0 0; 0 0).
`2.` I am setting it as `self.tableView.tableHeaderView = parentView;`

Comment: @RoboticCat You absolutely do **not** have to initialize a UIView with `initWithFrame:`. It's very common in a full Auto-Layout-ized app to only use `alloc/init` or `new`. In fact, where forced to do so, I usually pass in CGRectZero. (Regardless, OP's code is definitely a vit vague.)

Comment: @greymouser: It might work but according to the Apple docs (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-BBCDCECG) the only two designated initialisers for a `UIView` class are `initWithFrame:` (from code) or `initWithCoder:` (from a xib/storyboard).  Don't rely on `init` always working as this may be an implementation detail.

Comment: @RoboticCat Yeah, passing around CGRectZero tends to work (where I'm forced to do so), but in most cases, it just feels so ugly. I suppose just using `new` could work by side-effect 100% of the time but also isn't "documentedly" correct. This makes me uneasy now. ;-) The header refers to it as the "default initializer", and that's a bit vague to determine if it means "only" or "the one you likely want". I'm leaning towards the former, especially with AutoLayout, specifying a default frame seems like an anachronism.